# Is FileCapture is Ok in python using pyshark module

Tags: python, networking, ip, logic, pcap

Is FileCapture is ok for python and if we face error when we use FileCapture so what version of python that have its library.
like.

pkts = pyshark.FileCapture("C:\Users\DELL PC\Downloads\filli.pcap")

for p in pkts:
if hasattr(p, 'tcp'):
print(p.tcp.srcport + ' -- ' + p.tcp.dstport)
if hasattr(p, 'udp'):
print(p.udp.srcport + ' -- ' + p.udp.dstport)def iterate_through_pcap(file_name):

I am facing errors and first error pkts=pyshark.FileCapture("C:\Users\DELL PC\Downloads\filli.pcap")

Comment: Would you add some examples in your question please?